# MVC3 Routing Not Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Any idea why this link is not found?

```
context.MapRoute(null, "Admin/CompanyUserDelete/{userprofileid}", new { controller = "Admin", action = "CompanyUserDelete", userprofileid = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

It is definded using the AreaRegistration class.

```
 public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(null, "Admin", new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" });

            context.MapRoute(null, "Admin/Users", new { controller = "Admin", action = "CompanyUsers" });
            context.MapRoute(null, "Admin/Users/Create", new { controller = "Admin", action = "CreateUser" });
            context.MapRoute(null, "Admin/Users/{userprofileid}", new { controller = "Admin", action = "CompanyUser" });

            context.MapRoute(null, "Admin/CompanyUserDelete/{userprofileid}", new { controller = "Admin", action = "CompanyUserDelete", userprofileid = UrlParameter.Optional });

            context.MapRoute(null, "Admin/Users/{userprofileid}/Photo", new { contro
ller = "Admin", action = "UserImage" });
}
</code></pre>
```

Here is the link not found.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "CompanyUserDelete", "Admin", new { area = "Admin", userprofileid = userItem.UserProfileId }, null)
```

Comment: You forgot to show which link in particular is not found. You only showed your Admin area route definitions.

Answer (score 0):

CompanyUserDelete doesn't declare the first parameter "area" you are sending over to it.

```
  context.MapRoute(null, "Admin/CompanyUserDelete/{userprofileid}", new { controller = "Admin", action = "CompanyUserDelete", userprofileid = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

but here you have  "area"

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "CompanyUserDelete", "Admin", new { area = "Admin", userprofileid = userItem.UserProfileId }, null)
```

Comment: Why does this one work? -->  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CompanyUser", "Admin", new { area = "Admin", userprofileid = userItem.UserProfileId }, null)

Comment: Steve Sanderson's book says that area= is a reserved routing parameter name

Comment: It is - in your MapRoute. Im not 100% sure but can you specify it in the parameters as such without it in the route. I'll have to research a bit on that. You do - Im assuming - have an action named CompanyUserDelete, right? What is its method signature?